# In fish shell, which command is equivalent to bash's compgen?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, fish

`compgen` is a useful command, and fish is an excellent command shell. But I cannot find an equivalent in fish.

I write one by myself:

```
function compgen --description 'Print a list of documented fish commands'
    bash -c "compgen $argv"
end
```

But I think it better to use the native one if any.

Answer (score 3):

This is an exceptionally old question, but for future readers who stumble across this, the fish shell equivalent of bash's `compgen`builtin is `complete -C`. With `-C/--do-complete` option, `complete` will attempt to find all possible completions for the string specified immediately following `-C`, and, naturally, if you do not provide any additional characters after the `-C`, `complete` will, "... try to find all possible completions for the current command line buffer."

You can read about the the `complete` command and all of its options on the [Fish Shell documentation page for this command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#complete).

Source: [Fish Shell GitHub Issue #2105](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2105)